# Aggregating by 3 months and 6 months

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

How to compute the average billing of each customer in the last 3 and 6 months. When there is not enough data in the 3 or 6 month window, the service registers the entry as `NaN` (or null).

The result need to be like this:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|customer|account|avg_invoices_last_3_months|avg_invoices_last_6_months|
+--------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|C1000   |A1100  |56,333                    |41,333                    |
|C1000   |A1200  |41,333                    |NaN                       |
```

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({' account': {0: ' A1100',
  1: ' A1100',
  2: ' A1100',
  3: ' A1100',
  4: ' A1100',
  5: ' A1100',
  6: ' A1200',
  7: ' A1200',
  8: ' A1100',
  9: ' A1300',
  10: ' A1300',
  11: ' A1300',
  12: ' A2100',
  13: ' A2100',
  14: ' A2100',
  15: ' A2100',
  16: ' A2100',
  17: ' A2100',
  18: ' A2100'},
 ' invoice': {0: 80000,
  1: 1000,
  2: 78000,
  3: 34000,
  4: 55000,
  5: 80000,
  6: 90000,
  7: 55000,
  8: 80000,
  9: 10000,
  10: 10000,
  11: 20000,
  12: 1000,
  13: 78000,
  14: 3000,
  15: 45000,
  16: 78000,
  17: 55000,
  18: 80000},
 ' month': {0: ' 2019-05-01',
  1: ' 2019-06-01',
  2: ' 2019-07-01',
  3: ' 2019-10-01',
  4: ' 2019-11-01',
  5: ' 2019-12-01',
  6: ' 2019-10-01',
  7: ' 2019-11-01',
  8: ' 2019-12-01',
  9: ' 2019-10-01',
  10: ' 2019-11-01',
  11: ' 2019-12-01',
  12: ' 2019-06-01',
  13: ' 2019-07-01',
  14: ' 2019-08-01',
  15: ' 2019-09-01',
  16: ' 2019-10-01',
  17: ' 2019-11-01',
  18: ' 2019-12-01'},
 'customer': {0: 'C1000',
  1: 'C1000',
  2: 'C1000',
  3: 'C1000',
  4: 'C1000',
  5: 'C1000',
  6: 'C1000',
  7: 'C1000',
  8: 'C1000',
  9: 'C1000',
  10: 'C1000',
  11: 'C1000',
  12: 'C2000',
  13: 'C2000',
  14: 'C2000',
  15: 'C2000',
  16: 'C2000',
  17: 'C2000',
  18: 'C2000'}})
```

I'm trying to make it with `rolling` function of `pandas`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is "now"? And what is "not enough data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert month column to datetime:

```
 df.month = pd.to_datetime(df.month)
```

Create periods for three months and six months :

```
mths_3 = pd.date_range(end = df.month.iat[-1], freq=pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3),periods=2)
mths_6 = pd.date_range(end = df.month.iat[-1], freq=pd.offsets.MonthBegin(6),periods=2)
```

Filter for the last three months/six months and create new dataframes for average invoices :

```
mth3 = (df.set_index("month")
         #filter for last three months
        .loc[mths_3]
        .groupby(["customer", "account"])
        .agg(avg_invoices_last_3_months=("invoice","mean"))
        )

mth6 = (df.set_index("month")
         #filter for last six months
        .loc[mths_6]
        .groupby(["customer", "account"])
        .agg(avg_invoices_last_6_months=("invoice","mean"))
        )
```

Combine the two dataframes :

```
pd.concat([mth3,mth6],axis=1)

                      avg_invoices_last_3_months    avg_invoices_last_6_months
customer    account     
  C1000     A1100         80000                         53666.666667
            A1300         20000                         20000.000000
  C2000     A2100         62500                         40500.000000
```

Comment: If I don't have data that completes the 3 or 6 months, how could I fill the line with `NaN` instead of the mean?

Comment: An example of that scenario could help

Comment: For example, when I run this command:
`mths_3 = pd.date_range(end = df_invoic.month.iat[-1], freq=pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3),periods=2)`
I receive this object:
`DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-01', '2019-12-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3MS')`


And it looks like it doesn't consider the months 10 and 11:
`df_invoic.set_index("month").loc[mths_3]`

Comment: on the same data u shared or  a diff data?

Answer (score 1):

To group by 3 months and 6 months and find the mean, you can do this. You can change the code to last 3 months and 6 months based on what "now" is:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
print(df.groupby(by=['account', 'customer', pd.Grouper(key='month', freq='3M')])['invoice'].agg('mean'))
print(df.groupby(by=['account', 'customer', pd.Grouper(key='month', freq='6M')])['invoice'].agg('mean'))
```

**Output:**

```
account  customer  month
 A1100   C1000     2019-05-31    80000.000000
                   2019-08-31    39500.000000
                   2019-11-30    44500.000000
                   2020-02-29    80000.000000
 A1200   C1000     2019-11-30    72500.000000
 A1300   C1000     2019-11-30    10000.000000
                   2020-02-29    20000.000000
 A2100   C2000     2019-08-31    27333.333333
                   2019-11-30    59333.333333
                   2020-02-29    80000.000000
Name: invoice, dtype: float64
account  customer  month
 A1100   C1000     2019-05-31    80000.000000
                   2019-11-30    42000.000000
                   2020-05-31    80000.000000
 A1200   C1000     2019-11-30    72500.000000
 A1300   C1000     2019-11-30    10000.000000
                   2020-05-31    20000.000000
 A2100   C2000     2019-11-30    43333.333333
                   2020-05-31    80000.000000
Name: invoice, dtype: float64
```